# What is the hybridisation in dimolybdenum?

Tags: transition-metals, hybridization

Dimolybdenum's $\mathrm{4s}$ and $\mathrm{4p}$ orbitals are full. It is going to use its $\mathrm{4d}$ and $\mathrm{5s}$ orbitals to form a sextuple bond (2 $\sigma$, 2 $\pi$, 2 $\delta$). I am wondering if the $\mathrm{4s}$ and $\mathrm{4p}$ orbitals are going to hybridize with the $\mathrm{4d}_{z^2}$ orbital (the one forming the first $\sigma$ bond) and the $\mathrm{5s}$, given the differences in energy. The hybridisation would be $\mathrm{ds^2p^3}$, which is certainly uncommon.

If so, do the $\mathrm{s}$ and $\mathrm{p}$ lone pairs always hybridize, even if they don't form any bonds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The electronic configuration of $\ce{Mo2}$ is given in [Bursten, B.E.; Cotton, F.A.; Hall, M.B. Dimolybdenum: nature of the sextuple bond. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1980,** *102 (20),* 6348–6349](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00540a034):

> $$\ldots\mathrm{
> 9\sigma_g^{1.88}
> 5\pi_u^{3.78}
> 2\delta_g^{3.42}
> 10\sigma_g^{1.92}
> 9\sigma_u^{0.08}
> 2\delta_u^{0.58}
> 5\pi_g^{0.22}
> 10\sigma_u^{0.12}
> }$$

Which can be simplified as:

$$\ldots\mathrm{
(9\sigma_g)^2
(5\pi_u)^4
(2\delta_g)^4
(10\sigma_g)^2
(9\sigma_u)^0
(2\delta_u)^0
(5\pi_g)^0
(10\sigma_u)^0
}$$

- $9\sigma_{\mathrm{g}}$ is not degenerate; it is $\mathrm{4d_{z^2}+4d_{z^2}}$.
- $5\pi_{\mathrm{u}}$ is doubly degenerate; it is $\mathrm{4d_{xz}+4d_{xz}}$ and $\mathrm{4d_{yz}+4d_{yz}}$.
- $2\delta_{\mathrm{g}}$ is doubly degenerate; it is $\mathrm{4d_{xy}+d_{xy}}$ and $\mathrm{d_{x^2-y^2}+d_{x^2-y^2}}$.
- $10\sigma_{\mathrm{g}}$ is not degenerate; it is $\mathrm{5s+5s}$.

---

Now, let us have a look at the beautiful 4d orbitals, kindly provided by our user [Philipp](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/16622/ph13-yet-another-philipp):

[image]

---

From here, you can see that **no hybridization is necessary**, because the $\mathrm{4d}$ and the $\mathrm{5s}$ orbitals can all form bonds within themselves.

Answer (score 6):

In $\ce{Mo2}$ the six bonding and six anti-bonding $\sigma(s), \sigma(d_{z^2}), \pi(d_{xz,yz})$ and $\delta(d_{xy})$ molecular orbitals with occupation numbers of less than 2 and more than 0, the [active space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_active_space), are only formed by $\ce{5s}$ and $\ce{4d}$ atomic orbitals (see [DHMO’s answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/60914/16622) for the $\ce{4d}$ atomic orbitals).

[image: MOs of Mo2]

So, to answer your questions:

1. *[Does] Dimolybdenum [...] use its $\ce{4d}$ and $\ce{5s}$ orbitals to form a sextuple bond (2 σσ, 2 ππ, 2 δδ)[?]*
   Yes, but the MOs are as described above.
2. *[Are] the $\ce{4s}$ and $\ce{4p}$ orbitals [...] going to hybridize with the $\ce{4d_{z^2}}$ orbital [...] and the $\ce{5s}$[?]*
   No, they don’t hybridize the way you imagine it.
3. *[Do] the s and p lone pairs always hybridize, even if they don't form any bonds?*
   That question is *de facto* answered, as there is no hybridization.

---

(The shown molecular orbitals and the occupation numbers result from a fully relativistic (DKH2) CASSCF(12,12)/def2-QZVP calculation with ORCA 3.0.3; RI was used. The calculation is based on [A. C. Borin, J. P. Gobbo, B. O. Roos, *Chem. Phys.* **2008**, *343*, 210-216](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemphys.2007.05.028).)